# Android support libraries - diff versions

Tags: android-studio

An error crept into my project last night, somehow between builds. I didn't change anything, other than a bit of code, and it went from working to not, with this error - source code does not match the bytecode.

That led to a round of updating everything (gradle etc). Now a different error is occurring.

The error is;

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification. Found versions 25.2.0, 24.2.1. Examples include com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0.

Here's a copy of my build.gradle;

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "au.com.me.myproject"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
//compile 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:24.2.1'
//compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
//compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.1'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.6.2'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
 }
```

I can't work out where the support-compat:25.2 dependency is coming from. I've done a clean>rebuild. 
Any idea how to fix this? thanks all :)

**UPDATE**

Gradle View shows that com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.6.2 has a dependency on com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.2, which in turn has a com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 dependency. (assuming I'm reading it correctly).

Comment: you can try a project search to look for the string 25.2.0. It will give you the occurrence of that version in your app project

Comment: Thanks Ezio. I've done that. There are none. I've done a dependency report and it's littered with references to 25.2, but I don't know WHY. Such as this; Error:+--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0